# Unknown error executing gpgv

Tags: linux, debian, aptitude

I have a single deb entry:

```
# cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb ftp://debian.uchicago.edu/debian testing main contrib non-free
```

I get this glitch when I update:

```
#aptitude update
...
W: GPG error: ftp://debian.uchicago.edu testing InRelease: Unknown error executing gpgv
W: GPG error: ftp://debian.uchicago.edu testing InRelease: Unknown error executing gpgv
```

Didn't find any solutions on the net. May be there is someone here, who can help?

Thanx.

Comment: What happened if you just execute `gpgv` yourself from the same prompt?

Comment: Nothing happens, it just waits for input

Comment: # gpgv
_ -- cursor blinking

Comment: So at least you have a seemingly working `gpgv` binary. That's good to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just ran into this problem myself.

Seems like this is a problem with corrupted downloads.  There's more information in this bug: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=657561

Per the last email there, going into /var/lib/apt/lists/ and deleting the files in question then running apt-get update again seems to fix it for me.